# How to reduce the sync interval between Outlook <-> Exchange to less than 15 seconds?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am working on an EWS Managed API application that is monitoring all events on an Exchange Server. The problem is that it seems Outlook clients only sync with Exchange every 15 seconds or so, meaning that for testing purposes, every call requires a 15 second delay before it can be tested.

Is there any way to lower the interval in Outlook so that it syncs with Exchange more frequently (eg, every 5 seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the above timers if needed by modifying the following registry keys;

Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\\Outlook\Cached Mode

```
Value name: Download
Value type: REG_DWORD
Default value: 0000001e (30 seconds)

Value name: Upload
Value type: REG_DWORD
Default value: 0000000f (15 seconds)

Value name: Maximum
Value type: REG_DWORD
Default value: 0000003c (60 seconds)
```

Comment: Yea, I saw an article about this, but it doesn't seem to do anything - even after reducing these intervals, Outlooks only sends messages to Exchange every 15 seconds.

Comment: Are you making the changes on the client side?

Comment: Yes, although I just saw an article that says that this registry fix only works in Outlook 2007 and earlier. I'm using Outlook 2010, so this doesn't seem to be a solution.

Comment: Try HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchangeRPC\ParametersSystem and create a REG_DWORD entitled “Maximum Polling Frequency” value 5000

http://www.kraftkennedy.com/mailbox-sync-delays-with-outlook-2003-and-exchange-2010/

Best I could find, otherwise I have failed you :/